# Asp.Net login system convert to a captive portal

Tags: asp.net, network-programming

I have a asp.net web application(with login). i want to convert my login into a captive portal,(for wifi hotspot) how can i do this? i have an AP here. ubiquity picostation2.
any help will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with DNS Redirector

See: http://dnsredirector.com/pages